# Adding Jar dependency in gradle custom plugin

Tags: groovy, gradle

Assuming all my Gradle plugin user going to have a MYAPP_HOME sys variable set in there system
in MYAPP_HOME page i have a jar at $MYAPP_HOME/lib/mylib.jar

i am writing my own plugin....

I can find the MYAPP_HOME variable is set and fine the jar exists..

How can i add this jar dependency in my custom gradle plugin... ? when user runs my plugin say compileMyplugin my custom gradle plugin need to set the $MYAPP_HOME/lib/mylib.jar jar as compiler dependent

How to do this any one help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin just needs to do:

```
project.dependencies {
    compile project.files("${System.getenv("MYAPP_HOME")}/lib/mylib.jar"))
}
```

PS: In general, I wouldn't recommend relying on an environment variable and the availability of a Jar on the local file system. Instead, I'd publish the Jar to an artifact repository or put it under source control.

Comment: i am trying to use javafx part of this work :) javafx dont have a jar yet :P

Comment: I can also add using DependencyHandler with  dep.convention.plugins.pluginname  right ?